# How do I create a topic in a running container instance of spotif/kafka from bash

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have Kafka running as a container, and i want to create a topic.

When i attempt the following command:

```
docker exec -it [container_id] /bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

I receive the following error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/kafka-topics.sh\": stat /bin/kafka-topics.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
```

How can i accomplish the creation of a topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the `kafka-topics.sh` tool is not in `/bin`!

A quick look at the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/spotify/docker-kafka/blob/master/kafka/Dockerfile#L8) shows it's under `/opt/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0`

Try:

```
docker exec -it [container_id] /opt/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```